# Highstock Two Panes, Candlestick and Volume - Volume Series Move into Prices Pane on iPad

Tags: highcharts

When viewing the example http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume on iPad, I discovered that whenever I pan the chart leftwards/rightwards, the entire Volume series will move upwards considerably and into the OHLC pane. Has anyone encountered same issue?

Answer (score 0):

It was known bug (https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2000) but should be fixed in the master version:

http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js